# List display not working on server

Tags: python, django

I have a very weird problem. I added an IntegerField called "count" to a client model like so...

```
class Client(models.Model):
    ...
    count = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
```

In views.py, I set count according to the count of the previous client when creating a new client.

I'm also displaying count on the list display of my ClientAdmin.

```
class ClientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    list_display=(..., 'count')
```

After adding "count" to my Client model, I ran the following commands:

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations
python3 manage.py migrate
```

All this code worked very well on my localhost, and the "count" field also shows up on the list display.

Now, I committed and pushed all these files (the model, admin.py, and the new migration files) to git and pulled them on the server. I also ran python3 manage.py migrate on the server.

However, the admin on the live site (server) does not show "count" on the list display. Moreover, it does not update the count variable for new clients. The old clients have count set to 0, but not shown on the list display (I verified the values from the shell).

What might be causing this? I tried restarting gunicorn, but it did not help.

Comment: Have you tried deleting any .pyc files that might exist? Very rarely one of these files won't get recompiled and you'll see weird one-off issues like that.

Comment: Nice idea. Just tried that, but doesn't seem to work in this particular case. I'm totally stumped.

Comment: Yeah, that is very strange. Perhaps the gunicorn processes didn't actually get restarted?

Comment: Wow, it seems that was the problem. 

I did this: ps aux| grep gunicorn | grep myproject | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs kill -HUP

...and now it works fine. 

You're a saint, Brandon. :)